# Does the measure $\sum \frac{n_i}{n} \log^d(\frac{n}{n_i})$ has a name?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Does the measure $\sum_i \frac{n_i}{n} \log^d(\frac{n}{n_i})$ has a name? 
  - It matches the [information theory's entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) when $d=1$ and $\sum_i n_i = n$, but
  - it does not seem to match the definition of [Renyi's entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy) nor other variants in higher dimensions.
  - Me and my student wonder if it could be used to describe the complexity of a Maxima algorithm in high dimension.

Comment: It doesn't match with the Information Entropy. Indeed, what you have inside the sum is

$$ \frac{n_i}{n} \log n - \frac{n_i}{n}\log n_i$$

It matches only if, in addition to $d = 1$, you have also $n = 1$.

Comment: @Beta Are you sure? The Shannon entropy **is** defined as $\sum_i p_i \log_2 \frac{1}{p_i}$ where $(p_i)_i$ are the probabilities. Here, implicitly the OP seems to assume $\sum_i n_i = n$, so...

Comment: @ClementC. : Thanks, you answered faster than me, I added the definition of $n$ in the text of the question, sorry for the previous omission.

Comment: @ClementC. Ok now it fits! Details, guys, details. Nothing has to be left unknown.

Answer (score 1):

i have had a class in thermodynamics where i saw this measure. it was in german though and googleling the name did not get very good results though. Still i found that the English name is "uncertainty measure". the German version is "Unschärfe-maß"

Comment: the objective of any entropy measure is to "measure uncertainty", so the term would apply to all entropy measures, not only this one. Can you remember in which chapter and course you saw this expression (with the exponentiation to the d-th power on the log and not anywhere else)?

Comment: It was in theoretische physik IV with professor knorr at tu berlin.  he speaks of this measure, but has defined it in a slightly different way. you can find his lecture notes here http://www.itp.tu-berlin.de/menue/lehre/lv/ss_2015/pflichtveranstaltungen_bachelorstudium/theoretische_physik_iv_thermodynamik_und_statistik/  i do not

Comment: know for what purpose you need it, prof. knorr does motivate it and makes some applications of it. in chapter 1 or 2 he defines it on matrices though, basically a general case. later in the script there are also scalarvalued problems, also check the homework. it's in german and his handwriting is messy, but it's a very comprehensive description. hope it helps